# jquery $.get success callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to access the result of my query despite checking in browser network(xhr) and seeing the data is returned successfully from api. But I can't even console.log the returned data. Not sure what's going on.

Here's my code:

```js
// const url='/../../_public/api/news.php'; // does not work
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3' // works

let getHandle = () => {
return new Promise(function (resolve){
    $.get(url, {endpoint: 'titles', param: 'titles'}, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        resolve(response);
    })
})    
}

getHandle().then((res) => {
console.log(res);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `Promise()` constructor; the object returned by `$.get()` is a thenable and you can pass it to [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), allowing the JavaScript engine to juggle the `resolve` and `reject` callbacks for you.

Comment: @Carsten Massmann 
My php backend (api) returns data as expected. Hence I don't think there's a problem with the url. The problem is that I'm unable to use the data when it comes back to frontend

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` produce, when you use your API?

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem. And I put it there to check.
But like I said, in developer tools, Network under Fetch/XHR, I can see the returned data @CarstenMassmann

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your **api url**, you need to start the local dev server with your PHP backend and change the url to something like `'/api/news.php'`

// I tested your code with the json placeholder API and it works

Comment: Yep, an absolute path starting with "/../" won't work.